# Find the indices of matching elements of two lists

Tags: vb.net, list, loops, for-loop, indices

vb.NET

I have two lists (listA and listB) and want to return a new list (listC) containing listB’s indices of the matching elements when compared to listA.

So, let’s say: listA = 3,4,5 and listB = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. I’d like listC to return 2,3,4 because those are the indices of the matches in listB.

The following code will return the matching values of listA and listB in listC.

```
Dim commonlist = listA.Intersect(listB).ToList()
For each common As String In commonlist
listC.Add(common)
Console.WriteLine(common)
Next common
```

How can I return the indices to listC, or a new listD for that matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Dim listC = listA.Select(Function(itemA) listB.IndexOf(itemA)).ToList()
```

In case you're not familiar with LINQ, the `Select` method takes a function to map items in a list to a new list. It is completely up to you what that mapping function does. It's commonly getting a single property value from the items but, in your case, it's getting the index of the items in the other list.

`Select` returns an `IEnumerable(Of T)` and that's all you need if all you plan to do is run a `For Each` loop over it, but you can call `ToList` to create a `List(Of T)` if that's what you want.

EDIT:

I think that I may have misinterpreted the question slightly. I'll leave my original answer as what I have done is basically the `listD` requested in the question but I'll add information about getting the items and the indexes.

Here is one option:

```vb
Dim listA As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3, 9}
Dim listB As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

Dim listC = listA.Select(Function(a) Tuple.Create(a, listB.IndexOf(a))).
                  Where(Function(ta) ta.Item2 <> -1).
                  ToList()

For Each ta In listC
    Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}; Index: {1}", ta.Item1, ta.Item2)
Next
```

That code will create a list of `Tuples` where each one contains a value from `listA` and the index of that value in `listB`. Those values not in both lists are excluded.

If you want something a bit nicer than a `Tuple` then you can create a `Dictionary`:

```vb
Dim listA As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3, 9}
Dim listB As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

Dim dictionaryC = listA.Select(Function(a) Tuple.Create(a, listB.IndexOf(a))).
                        Where(Function(ta) ta.Item2 <> -1).
                        ToDictionary(Function(ta) ta.Item1,
                                     Function(ta) ta.Item2)

For Each key In dictionaryC.Keys
    Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}; Index: {1}", key, dictionaryC(key))
Next
```

If you specifically want two separate lists then you can do this:

```vb
Dim listA As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3, 9}
Dim listB As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

Dim listC = listA.Intersect(listB).ToList()
Dim listD = listC.Select(Function(c) listB.IndexOf(c)).ToList()

For i = 0 To listC.Count - 1
    Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}; Index: {1}", listC(i), listD(i))
Next
```